# Performance issues with repeated calls to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to get appsetting values?

Tags: .net, performance, appsettings

I'm working on a code base that has a lot of identical ConfigurationManager.AppSetting calls scattered throughout.

> Does this sound like a possible performance issue?

Or because the data being very small is trivial and not 'expensive'? Constantly going back to the file to get the data, or does the .NET runtime cache the file/values/calls?

If this isn't a performance issue is it just a disorganized approach to accessing the application configuration values, and should just be re-factored to be cleaner and consistent implementation of accessing the settings?

Comment: Personally I use ConfigurationManager and I have no issues with it and I find it very simple for changing settings without having to recompile the issue. Unless you can get another form of persistent memory to save your settings then file access through the ConfigurationManager seems best to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would say it's more of the code maintainability issue than performance issue. A simple dictionary lookup on `AppSettings` isn't going to be a problem unless you have code that tries to perform lookup on `AppSettings` in a loop that runs say hundred times. Surely such a code will cause performance problem. But even more important is you will have `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"]` throughout your codebase. You are introducing a magic string. If you have to change the key in your configuration file, you will have to do a thorough search and replace in all your projects. Moreover, we usually make some decision based on the value stored in appSettings. It's not always straighforward read and use the value as-is. Sometimes you take decision based on the value. For ex,

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DebugMode"] == "yes")
  do this
else
  do that
```

You might be repeating this logic in hundred places. Now let's say you need to add another condition there:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DebugMode"] == "yes" || ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InternetNotAvailable"] == "yes")
  do this
else
  do that
```

This gets messy. Your code starts to stink.

So, I always recommend my dev team to never use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` anywhere in the code. Use some static class where you read the configuration values and all such decisions are precached into a single variable. For ex,

```
static class ConfigHelper
{
  private readonly static bool ExternalWebserviceCallAllowed = ConfiguationManager.AppSettings["DevMode"] == "false" && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InternetAvailable"] == "true";

}

.
.
if (ConfigHelper.ExternalWebserviceCallAllowed)
   do this
else
   do that
```

This is not only better in performance, but also highly maintainable and extensible code.

Comment: Thanks, I am seeing this kind of pattern in other code bases too.

Comment: ConfiguationManager reads the web configuration file once and then caches for subsequent reads. It not reads the web configuration file every time. If we store the app settings in a static variable then we are storing them two times in memory. One for ConfiguationManager and another for our static variable. If there are many app setting then all of them will be stored two times in memory. To improve this can we make a property instead of a variable?

Answer (score 3):

A few things here.

1. You can validate if this is a performance issue by using something like ANTS Profiler or DotTrace that allows you to inspect the performance of the application
2. I would say that you MIGHT be open for some issues in the future if you scatter calls all over the place, think for example if you decide to change the name of one of the app settings, it could be disastrous.  I personally recommend centralizing this type of thing if for any reason to allow for future changes.
3. From a performance perspective, be careful to not "pre-optimize" something that is just not needed, you might end up adding more complexity when it just isn't needed.